# Help Solving a Differential Equation with Trigonometric Functions

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am having some trouble solving/understanding:
$$
b\cos(bx)\sin(2y) = -2\cos(2y)\sin(bx)\frac{dy}{dx}
$$
for $y(x)$, where $b\in\mathbb{R}$ is constant.

My attempt:
\begin{align}
b\tan(2y) &= -2\tan(bx)\frac{dy}{dx} \\
b\cot(bx) &= -2\cot(2y)\frac{dy}{dx} \\
\int b\cot(bx)dx &= \int -2\cot(2y) dy \\
-\log(\sin(bx)) &= \log(\sin(2y))-C_1 \\
y(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left( \exp(C_1 - \log(\sin(bx))) \right) \\
y(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left( e^{C_1}\csc(bx) \right) \\
\end{align}

Now, this solution  lines up with Mathematica, but it is sort of bizarre.

Problem 1: the original DE is well-defined everywhere, but this solution has singularities. *Edit: it is not actually well-defined when the $dy/dx$ has been zeroed out.*

Problem 2: most importantly, notice that $y(x)=\frac{n\pi}{2}$ for $n\geq 0,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a solution to the DE. But the solution does not really reflect this. What am I missing?

Comment: ***NB:*** The original ODE is ***not*** well-defined where $\cos 2y = 0$ or where $\sin bx = 0$; you can't infer the value of  $dy/dx$ at such points.

Comment: @RobertLewis Hm, thanks. What does that say about $y$ though? If I simply specify initial conditions $y(0)=y_0$, for example, and try to solve for $C_1$, it tells me $C_1=-\infty$.

Comment: I don't have time to go into detail right now, but if you stay away from singularities, i.e. points where the coefficient of $dy/dx$ vanish, things should work out fine.  Hope this helps.